# Export the result from promise then block

Tags: javascript, promise

I am fairly new to js and promise world, and I have read many articles about promise, callback, async/await.

I have the function `getAllPost()` that request all the posts from an uri.

```js
// get-content.js
export async function getAllPost(){
    let uri     = "http://127.0.0.1/posts";
    let request = axios.get(uri);
    return request;
}
export default getAllPost;
```

I am trying to use the result from `getAllPost()` for mapping the content, and I want to export the `posts`.

```js
// posts.js
import * as Navi from 'navi'
import slugify from 'slugify'
import { getAllPost } from './get-content'


let getPost = getAllPost();
let articles;
getPost.then((response) => {
  articles = response;
})

console.log(articles); // undefined.


let postDetails = articles.map( content => {


  let title = content.title;
  let slug = slugify(content.title);
  let date = new Date(content.date);
  let contentKey = content.contentKey;

  return {contentKey, title, slug, date}

})

let posts = postDetails.map(
  ({contentKey, title, slug, date}, i) => 

  ({

    getPage: Navi.map(async () => {

      return Navi.route({
        title,  
        getData: (req, context) => ({
          date,
          slug,
        }),
        getView: async () => {
          let MDXComponent = await getContent(contentKey);
          return { MDXComponent }
        }

      })
    }), 

    slug,

  })


)

export default posts;
```

I understand that the `articles` is `undefined` because js wouldn't wait for `getPost.then()` finish.

I tried to put the entire `let postDetails = articles.map(...)` and `let posts = postDetails.map(...)` in `getPost.then((response) => { ... })` block, but in that case, I can't export `posts`.

```js
getPost.then((response) => {
  let articles = response;
  let postDetails = articles.map( content => {
     ...
  })

  let posts = postDetails.map(
     ...
  )

  export default posts;  // compile failed.
})
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for the suggestions, but I should be more clear.

Here is how I will use the posts:

```js
import { chunk, fromPairs } from 'lodash'
import posts from './posts'

// posts has to be an array at this point.
let chunks = chunk(posts, n)
```

I guess I have to re-write `chunk()` to allow callback?
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/chunk.js

Comment: Hi Xuan Cao,

I could be wrong, but I think, you can't export from within a `then` callback (what if the function is never called?).
You could, however, export the method `getPost` and then call it elsewhere.

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki, yes, you are right. It can't be exported from then block.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAllPosts` function is a default export so you don't need to wrap it in curly braces when you import it into the next script.

Your `articles` is undefined because your trying to use it outside of the promise function.

When you call the function you can start doing your then functions straight away rather than passing the response to another variable...

```js
getAllPost().then(articles => {
  // articles.map etc...
  // The rest of your code must live inside this function
  // because anything outside of here won't wait for the
  // articles promise. 
  // This is async world, outside isn't. 
})
```

The other thing you can use if you don't like staying inside the promise function is async await, it's much cleaner and easier to understand.

```js
let articles
try {
  articles = await getAllPost()
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
// Do stuff with articles...
```

*Note* the above code must be inside an async function though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like that:

```
export async function fetchArticles() {
    let uri     = "http://127.0.0.1/posts";
    return await axios.get(uri);
}
```

```
async function getPosts(){
    const articles = await fetchArticles();
    let postDetails = articles.map(...);
    let posts = postDetails.map(...);

    return posts
}

export default getPosts; // you can't export posts directly, you should export a function and call it to get posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Async-await is sugar syntax around promise api. Writing async await wont make you code synchronous.

```
let getPost = getAllPost();
let articles;
getPost.then((response) => {
  articles = response;
})

console.log(articles); // undefined.
```

here when you call getPost, u get arricles in callback. However,  console.log(articles); // undefined. and other line will execute before even then called. If you want to lazy initilaize something u have to await for the result than call something else. Below i have given example.

```
(async function() {
 const articles = await getAllPost()

console.log(articles); // not undefined.

let postDetails = articles.
/// rest of the code
})()
```

Similarly, u have to solve export posts call.

Comment: Totally agree Async-await is sugar syntax. I tried iife, but I still need `.then` block to get data from `articles`; and yes, I still need to figure out a way to export the `posts`, which I can't export it inside then().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you have forgot to add the keyword `await` infront of your axios request:

```
// get-content.js
export default async function(){
   let uri     = "http://127.0.0.1/posts";
   let request = await axios.get(uri);
   return request.data;
}
```

Its undefined because you send an request with `axios.get(uri)` and that request is actually returning an result, but it takes some time to get the result lets say about 100 ms. In that time, 100ms for example, the function is already finished and returning undefined. With `await` you can let promises waiting for your request till you get an response.

Second problem:
Because `getAllPost()` is returning the result itself you can write your code like this:

```
import getAllPost from "./get-content";
let articles =  getAllPost();
```

Comment: I think `articles` is promise since `getAllPost()` is `async` function, so I still need to use `.then` block to get the data from `request.data`.

Comment: if you use await, then u dount need callback then function. Please read promise/asycn/await to make things clear.